# How to manage null values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem

I made a merge of several AsterGdem blocks near Egypt and Israel. I have portions of the Dead and Mediterranean Seas. Since near Galilea elevations are below sea level this makes the following problem

When I define the null value as 0, the resulting image shows the seas as null values, which is correct, nevertheless, I also have some pixels inland forming a kind of a contour with the null value as 0.

What I want to accomplish is to have the seas as null values and inland elevation information correct also

Thanks before hand

Gerardo

Comment: what? the correct number/height 0 you would like to be null? null:= a reference that can be everything. So if the inland pixels have null as value, they are broken?

Comment: No, I want to handle correctly both elevation and null values, in my case I have elevation values with 0 and the portions of sea in my geotiffs have a value of 0 also.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue (see the QGIS bugtracker and also the QGIS developer mailing list, where a question about this problem was sent yesterday). In the development version of QGIS the rasters and their symbology are being overhauled, so fortunately this issue is going to be fixed in the next future.

Comment: This is issue may have been fixed today. You can try the next development release tomorrow, using the osgeo4w installer on Windows or for example the nightly build repository for Debian or Ubuntu.